# Eclipse plugin with different views (windows)

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I am trying to create a plugin in eclipse that can launch multiple windows, i.e more than one classes extending ViewPart. The idea is that I can got to :

> window -> show view -> *my_category* -> *my_view1* or -> *my_view2*

and so on...

I tried adding multiple views in the extensions page under **org.eclipse.ui.views** and also have the code to open it when clicked, but for some reason, it just doesn't work. I don't get any errors, but the 2nd or 3rd view just wouldn't show up.

Am I missing something here? Can someone please guide me on this?

Thanks

Comment: Please post your plugin.xml for starters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your specific question involves opening the Error Log view (It's usually under the general category in Window -> Show View).  If your code is executing but failing for any reason you should see messages in the error log view.  These errors are also logged in the log file in the .metadata folder

Comment: got it! I found the issue with my code in the error log view and fixed it. It works fine now. Thanks Chris!